# .Net Core + React + Identity server. returnUrl returns 'template Url' instead of 'Url from which I was redirected'

Tags: c#, reactjs, .net-core, asp.net-identity, identityserver4

I have net7.0 + React + Identity server (template project with user identity)
The problem is: After Authorization I redirected back not on a page from which I was redirected to Authorization.

Example : I Am on a page (with allowed anonymous) /user then i redirected to page user/approve/59417a20-0347-4901-943b-534930241adb
(59417a20-0347-4901-943b-534930241adb - user id)

user/approve/:userId requires authorization there for i redirected to Login page after successful authorization I want to be redirected back to  'user/approve/59417a20-0347-4901-943b-534930241adb'  but I am redirected to 'user/approve/:userId'
AppRoutes are:

```
const AppRoutes = [
  
  {
    path: '/user/approve/:userId',
    requireAuth: true,
    element: <User />
  },
  {
    path: '/user/:userId',
    element: <User />
  },
  {
    path: '/user',
    element: <User />
  },
  {
    path: '/',
    index: true,
    element: <Navigate to ='/user' replace />
  },
  ...ApiAuthorzationRoutes
];
```

Server side configuration are generic

```
app.UseCors("MyPolicy");

if (app.Environment.IsDevelopment())
{
    app.UseDeveloperExceptionPage();
    app.UseSwagger();
    app.UseSwaggerUI(c =>
    {
        c.SwaggerEndpoint("/swagger/v1/swagger.json", "Users v1");
    });
}
else
{
    app.UseExceptionHandler("/Error");
    app.UseHsts();
}

app.UseHttpsRedirection();
app.UseStaticFiles();
app.UseRouting();

app.UseAuthentication();
app.UseIdentityServer();
app.UseAuthorization();

app.MapControllerRoute(
    name: "default",
    pattern: "{controller}/{action=Index}/{id?}");
app.MapRazorPages();

app.MapFallbackToFile("index.html");

app.Run();
```

Cors:

```
 builder.Services.AddCors(o => o.AddPolicy("MyPolicy", builder =>
 {
     builder.AllowAnyOrigin()
            .AllowAnyMethod()
            .AllowAnyHeader();
 }));
```

To go to page I use

```
import { useNavigate } from "react-router-dom";
...
const navigate = useNavigate();
...
navigate(/user/approve/${user.id})
```

Comment: Are you using two step authentication.  Step one is to make a request to get a token.  Step 2 is to make query using token.  Two step you do not have a route in step one so no need to return to where code left off.

Comment: No Just 1 step Auth. Template project

Comment: Are you sure your CORS is not set to two step?  https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68993824/cors-issues-with-window-open-and-oauth2

Comment: 1. On public page (/user) and trying to access private page (/user/approve/12312) 
this page was in browser input line

2. I am redirected to Auth page (Entering login and password).

3. I am logging in and redirected to:

4. I am authorized but returned to page 'user/approve/:userId'
  Nothing more happens. 
  If I try to access any pages which requires Authentication i can do it (I am 
 Authenticated)
It seems to me It one step.

Comment: Cors is part of the network and not you application.  I network Admin controls the Cors policy.  Your code can add additional restrictions but cannot change the network settings.  You can try GUEST : [Authorize(Roles = RolesConvention.Guest)]